# linux watchdog and systemd watchdog

Tags: systemd, watchdog

Any way to register application with systemd watchdog at runtime ?
I mean don't use systemd unit file, via systemd API for example

Linux watchdog is used for system reset only ? Can it be used for application reset ?

Answer (score 19):

Systemd's watchdog can be mainly used for 3 different actions:

- hardware reset (leveraging the CPU hardware watchdog exposed at /dev/watchdog). This is enabled by the `RuntimeWatchdogSec=` option in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`
- application reset, as long as this is foreseen in the systemd unit definition
- system reset as a fallback measure in response to multiple unsuccessful application resets. Also defined in the systemd unit

example unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Little Daemon
Documentation=man:mylittled(8)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mylittled
WatchdogSec=30s
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=4
StartLimitAction=reboot-force
```

The example is taken from: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html, which gives a pretty complete overview of what and how you can use the watchdog service.

Comment: Example how to actually implement software watchdog for application reset would be useful. That Example unit file doesn't help at all out of context.

Answer (score 4):

The Linux watchdog daemon should be used for system reset jobs, though it can also run a "repair binary" on persistent errors that could be used to fix or restart a process. Generally speaking, to monitor daemon processes and restart them you should use the init/upstart/systemd supported methods as already answered and keep the watchdog operation for the most serious "only a reboot is likely to fix things" situations.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks Paul.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions or expectations in your question.

## System watchdog

When it comes to the Linux service watchdog it is intended to detect system (OS, Linux) issues (broken, frozen, ...) and it works in the following way:

1. there is a special service (supported with hardware, ideally) that is "telling" basically: "All is ok, I am alive!"
2. it tells it constantly, periodically
3. there is an observer (hardware ideally) which, if not informed for a longer than expected period, will decide that the system became unresponsive and will reboot the system (by software or hardware reboot)
4. hopefully if it was a specific freezing with a new reboot the system would recover
5. if something is seriously wrong the system will again trigger the watchdog and the system will repeat rebooting

## Application watchdog

On the other hand, there is an interest in watching an application/service health.

1. for example you might want to be sure if the application dies you would like to restart it (for that you should start it as a service, ideally through [`systemd` mechanism)](https://linuxhandbook.com/create-systemd-services/) or
2. if you want to be sure that the app is not frozen you want to have an external watchdog service to which your app would report "All good, I am alive". One of these app-supporting watchdogs is [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/)