# Reboot a linux when rootfs gets unavailable

Tags: kernel, reboot, watchdog

How can one make a Linux-based device to reboot once its rootfs gets unavailable?

There is software watchdog available only.

The problem is that rootfs gets mounted from `NFS`. When I stop the NFS server, the device gets blocked. I want it to get rebooted though.
How can I achieve this?

I.e: there is a problematic rootfs, is there anything on the kernel level that can reset the whole system?
I don't care of open/corrupted files and resources.

Note: I don't have the kernel sources for this architecture. The device is headless, no monitor or keyboard is attached.
There is a root console with `agetty` (defined in `/etc/inittab`).

Comment: The software watchdog is inside the kernel so it should be possible to trigger it just as normal. Loop: read contents of rootfs. If no error then reset watchdog timer. This will catch unblocked read errors and blocked reads

Comment: Where shall I put this loop? Into a bash script?

Comment: The problem is that once rootfs goes down, even root console (via `agetty`) seems blocked.

Comment: Related - [linux watchdog and systemd watchdog](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308677/100397)

Comment: There is no hardware watchdog available. Even if there is `/dev/watchdog`, it can be sw-based implementation. I'm using it, but once rootfs goes down, it seems all process get blocked.

Comment: Even though `/dev/watchdog` is software only, it should be managed inside the kernel and therefore outside the effect of a blocked rootfs.

Comment: Okay, but believe me, it is not rebooting the device. What can I check, if even agetty is blocked?

Comment: If I get time this weekend I'll see if I can create a similar configuration. It probably won't be a rootfs NFS mount, but maybe we can proof-of-concept with a different one

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state if you have a physical keyboard attached, but if you do, then the ["Magic SysRq Keys"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) might help. In your case

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for emergency sync-to-disk, and
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for immediate reboot

should do the job. Notice that for this to work it is necessary that these key combinations are not deactivated, see the setting in `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` which is an ORed bitmask of allowed SysRq-Actions (reproduced from [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/admin-guide/sysrq.html)):

```
  2 =   0x2 - enable control of console logging level
  4 =   0x4 - enable control of keyboard (SAK, unraw)
  8 =   0x8 - enable debugging dumps of processes etc.
 16 =  0x10 - enable sync command
 32 =  0x20 - enable remount read-only
 64 =  0x40 - enable signalling of processes (term, kill, oom-kill)
128 =  0x80 - allow reboot/poweroff
256 = 0x100 - allow nicing of all RT tasks
```

You can also trigger this from a shell script/program by writing to `/proc/sysrq-trigger`:

```
echo "b" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

This will work no matter what the settings in `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq` are, which only restrict keyboard-induced SysRq-events.

Comment: No, I have no keyboard nor monitor attached. Only a root console via `agetty`.

Comment: But the problem is once rootfs goes down, even this root console seems blocked.

Comment: so, in theory this could be good, but I would need something which can survive a broken rootfs. Otherwise, `/proc` can be still alive, but I have to start a program which can run in the memory and can write to this file once the rootfs gets unavailable. Do you have idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Daniel Ah, that's tricky; I cannot come up with a quick solution to this unfortunately ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need the mount option `onerror=panic` for your NFS root filesystem, but I’m not sure if it will work with NFS. You might also need to mount the NFS root filesystem with the NFS-specific mount option `soft` so it will time out and return an error instead of retrying forever.

**Note:** the `soft` mount option may cause file corruption and/or data loss, but in the comments you specifically said you don't care about that.

Worth a try, maybe?

Comment: how shall I config `onerror=panic`? If I write it to `fstab`, it results `invalid argument`.

Comment: `onerror` is ufs-specific. Can't applied to nfs mounts.